# Play remote audio stream on embedded Linux device using ALSA

Tags: audio, embedded, alsa, streaming

I have an embedded ARM Linux device with a speaker connected to it. So far I've successfully compiled `alsa-lib` and `alsa-utils` and installed on the target system.
I can list my device using `aplay -l`:

```
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: am3517evm [am3517evm], device 0: AIC23 tlv320aic23-hifi-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

and play a test wav file on it:

```
aplay -vv /opt/mtgr/piano.wav
```

But what I need is to play some remote stream. The workflow looks like the following: a remote client sends audio stream and my embedded Linux plays it on the speaker.

I guess that I need some server, maybe some RTP server or whatever. I haven't been able to find anything yet. Any help or advice will be appreciated .

Comment: And what is "remote" in your case: Over any Bluetooth profile? USB? TCP/IP? Maybe you could unveil your use case a little bit.

Comment: Yes, over network, TCP/IP. Already solved by transmitting the PCM stream over network using TCP sockets. Actually I have to compress the stream but that's the next step.